Can I Modify the value of property of z.object based selected language
I have simple input that is handled by react-hook-form
I have radio-buttons that I determin what is language that I make input's value for and in the end I assume that I make just request to the server and send the content that I typed in the input in json form like
const nameValue = {
en: 'Hi there',
ar: 'مرحبا'
}

and the schema that I made is something like this:
const createDeviceCategoryFormSchema = z.object({
  deviceCategory: z
    .string({
      required_error: 'Select the category of the device',
    })
    .refine((value) => value.length > 0, {
      message: 'Select the company of device-category',
    }), // it must be object converted to string

  name: z
    .string({ required_error: 'You need to fill this field' })
    .min(3, 'Device-category name must be greater than 3 characters')
    .max(25, 'Device-category name must be lower than 25 characters'),

  image: z
    .instanceof(FileList)
    .refine(
      (files) => {
        return files.length === 1;
      },
      {
        message: `You should select only one file`,
      },
    )
    .refine(
      (files) => {
        if (files.length === 0) return true;
        return (
          files.item(0) &&
          files.item(0)?.size <= fileConditions.CompanyImage.maxSize
        );
      },
      {
        message: `Maximum allowed file size is: ${fileConditions.CompanyImage.maxSize}`,
      },
    )
    .refine(
      (files) => {
        if (files.length === 0) return true;
        return (
          files.item(0) &&
          files.item(0)?.type.split('/')[1].toLowerCase() === 'png'
        );
      },
      {
        message: `The allowed image file type is "png"`,
      },
    ),
});

Here name is property attached to single input field, I need to make this property' value change from language to another based on radio-buttons that I mentioned earlier, So How can I make this with zod and reac-hook-form (Without making multiple input fields!)
